# componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed

Tags: react-native

I do not use componentWillMount method,but I still get the warning.It is trouble me. Help me,guys!
React-native 0.55

`Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary workaround, you can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount.`

Comment: It might be used by some package that you're importing, can you add the complete code for the file above?

Comment: Yes, most likely this warning is because of a third party library

Comment: you can add this `console.disableYellowBox = true;` in `App.js`, __*FYI*__ : the code will hide __*ALL*__ Warning in your App

Answer (score 1):

Yup..

In future versions of React componentWillMount will be called more than once, so you should use componentDidMount for network requests.

Instead use **"UNSAFE_componentWillMount()"**,

**Note**

This lifecycle was previously named componentWillMount. That name will continue to work until version 17.

Use to automatically update your components.

```
rename-unsafe-lifecycles codemod
```